# What is wrong with this Node Javascript one-line conditional?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here it is:

```
( result.username === user.username ) ? res.status( 500 ).json( "That username is already taken." ) : res.status( 500 ).json( "That email has already been used." )
```

Shouldn't this do the first thing, `res.status( 500 ).json( "That username is already taken." )`, if the condition is true? Instead, it says:

```
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
```

---

This works as expected.

```
if ( result.username === user.username ) return res.status( 500 ).json( "That username is already taken." )
else return res.status( 500 ).json( "That email has already been used." )
```

Sorry if I'm still not spotting the typo.

Comment: Please post the exact error message, and where it is pointing at.

Comment: Also, how does the line before this oneliner look like?

Comment: Does it work if the condition is false?

Comment: This really should either be an if/else statement or `res.status( 500 ).json( result.username === user.username ? "That username is already taken." ) : "That email has already been used." )`

Comment: possible duplicate of [immediate shorthand if statement crashes the app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27131613/1048572)?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will be ok:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {   
    (true) ? res.status( 500 ).json( "That username is already taken.") : res.status( 500 ).json( "That email has already been used." )
});

var server = app.listen(9000, function () {

var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

Answer (score -2):

The string in json() is not a JSON format,
Try:

```
res.status( 500 ).json({msg:"That username is already taken."})
```

Comment: You're not passing a JSON string either?

Comment: Also, that hardly would throw a `[TypeError: undefined is not a function]`

Comment: if ( result.username === user.username ) {res.status( 500 ).json( "That username is already taken." );} 
else {res.status( 500 ).json( "That email has already been used." );}  Does this replicate the problem?

Comment: You are missing semicolon at the end of of first code example